# Haskell Network.HTTP incorrectly downloading image

Tags: http, haskell, download

I'm trying to download images using the Network.HTTP module and having little success.

```
import Network.HTTP

main = do
  jpg <- get "http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/comics/irreg2557.jpg"
  writeFile "irreg2557.jpg" jpg where
       get url = simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= getResponseBody
```

The output file appears in the current directory, but fails to display under chromium or ristretto. Ristretto reports "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0c3 0xbf)".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
```

`String`. That's your problem, right there. `String` is for unicode text. Attempting to store binary data in it will lead to corruption. It's not clear in this case whether the corruption is being done by `simpleHTTP` or by `writeFile`, but it's ultimately unimportant. You're using the wrong type, and something is corrupting the data when confronted with bytes that don't make up a valid unicode encoding.

As for fixing this, newer versions of `HTTP` are polymorphic in their return type, and can handle returning the raw bytes in a `ByteString`.  You just need to change how you're writing the bytes to the file, so that it won't infer that you want a `String`.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Network.HTTP
import Network.URI (parseURI)

main = do
    jpg <- get "http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/comics/irreg2557.jpg"
    B.writeFile "irreg2557.jpg" jpg
  where
    get url = let uri = case parseURI url of
                          Nothing -> error $ "Invalid URI: " ++ url
                          Just u -> u in
              simpleHTTP (defaultGETRequest_ uri) >>= getResponseBody
```

The construction to get a polymorphic Request is a bit clumsy. If [issue #1](https://github.com/haskell/HTTP/issues/1) ever gets fixed then using `getRequest url` will suffice.

Comment: Your answer is slightly incorrect because `getRequest` returns a `Request_String`, which stops it from being polymorphic. I will edit in a version that works for me.